# has no method 'readOnly' and has no method 'attr'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to follow along with [Tom Dale's youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ga99hMi7wfY) for building a simple blog. I have cloned the ember-data master from GH and built it, however I am getting two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'readOnly'
```

thats from inside ember-data and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attr'
```

is from my first use of DS.attr in my model.  My code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/RyanHirsch/ember-showdown-blog/blob/master/app/scripts/app.js) as well as below

```
/* Ember and Ember-Data are shimmed in as deps */
define([], function () {
  'use strict';
  var App = Ember.Application.create();

  App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
  });

  App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('about');
  });

  App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.attr('string'),
    intro: DS.attr('string'),
    extended: DS.attr('string'),
    publishedAt: DS.attr('date')
  });

  App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Rails is Omakase",
    author: "d2h",
    publishedAt: new Date('12-27-2012'),
    intro: "There are lots of a la carte software",
    extended: "I want this for my ORM"
  }];

  return App;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.readonly()` is an Ember method used internally in the latest version of the data library that was only added between Ember.JS RC1 and RC2. If you want to use master Ember-Data, you need to use master Ember.

Comment: follow up, how do you we find the version of ember-data that works withEmber 1.0.0.pre, ember-data doesn't seem to have any tags.

Comment: @Chandler Try builds.emberjs.com?